# Why do i end up in an infinite loop when i read a file?

Tags: c, loops, file, infinite-loop

I'm trying my hardest to make this work but it just seems lite it doesn't want to.

The premise is simple. i'm trying to use fgetc to read a file and write the result in an array, stopping at any \n or EOF. It reads the line as intended but, for no apparent reason, as soon as the line ends, the program gets caught in an infinite loop. i tried using fgets, getline and even fscanf (i know it's not a good idea, but that was really my last one)

This is my fgetc attempt:

```
short ended = 0;
FILE *bRead = fopen(fdirs,"r");
char *dirscan[1024];
char scan;
short endln = 0;
while(ended==0) {
    for(int i=0;endln==0 && i<1024;i++) {
        if(i==1023) {
            dirscan[i]='\0';
            endln=1;
        }   else {
            scan = fgetc(bRead);
            if(scan == '\n' || scan == EOF) {
                dirscan[i]='\0';
                endln=1;
            } else {
                dirscan[i]=scan;
            }
        }
        printf("i= %d, s = %s\n",i,dirscan);
    }
    if(scan==EOF)
        ended=1;
}
fclose(bRead);
```

i even tried to delete the "if(scan==EOF)" but the program, looks like it never actually left the for loop while at the same time not even running the printf again and again

the file it reads (Edit:is created just before running this code and) looks like this:

```
0: .
0: .
```

and the printf writes this on the terminal:

```
i= 0, s = 0
i= 1, s = 0:
i= 2, s = 0: 
i= 3, s = 0: .
i= 4, s = 0: .
```

and neither keeps writing nor gives the terminal control afterwards

before you ask, yes i have other code under this one but i tested that one hundreds of time and it has no issues

Comment: if you wonder why the array is called "dirscan" it's because the file will hold a list of paths to directories

Comment: First of all check if `fopen` succeeds. What do you think happens if the file does not exist (happens very often)?.

Comment: the reason why i don't check for the file's existance is because it's being created and written just before this code is run. should've specified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems here.

The `fgetc` function returns an `int`, not a `char`.  The reason for this is that `EOF` is typically -1, which falls outside the range of a `unsigned char` which is returned after casting to an `int` in the normal case.

Change `scan` to an `int` to fix this.

```
int scan;
```

You also declared `dirscan` incorrectly:

```
char *dirscan[1024];
```

This creates an array of pointers, not an array of characters.  You instead want:

```
char dirscan[1024];
```

Then the reason for the infinite loop.  You never reset `endln` after you leave the `for` loop.  This means that on later iterations of the `while` loop you never enter the `for` loop.  So `scan` never changes, which means `ended` never changes.

Set `endln` to 0 before entering the `for` loop:

```
endln = 0;
for(int i=0;endln==0 && i<1024;i++) {
```

Finally, when you print `dirscan` at the end of the `for` loop, you don't have a null terminated string so you risk reading past the end of the array.

Either move this `printf` to the outside of the loop or just print one character at a time in the loop.

Comment: thank you, i'm completely blind. i probably did something just as stupid with the other functions but it's too late to check now. the printf was there just for testing purposes and will be deleted asap